# boto2: download object from s3 with one API call

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

I am using python and boto2 for an s3 project.

There is a file in s3, I want to get its contents by path name.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think it can't be done with one API call. 
First I need to call bucket.get_key and then key.get_content.

I would like to download the file contents with just one API call (the file is not big and should comfortably fit in an in-memory string)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: first call bucket.new_key, which locally creates a key object and does not incur in an API call.
Then use key.get_content.